# Laravel controller not working, on client side (java) getting socket timeout exception

Tags: java, php, laravel

I'm using a Laravel 5.0 application on production. Client communicates via API. But for some random clients, it's giving Socket Timeout Exception. There is no computational part, which could take even half-second to compute. In controller there are 1-5 queries based on input params, and it just returns response. In controller there is logging (`Log` facade), 1st line of controller is logging start of request (it's logging URL params). For the client requests which are getting timeout, I can see the first log line in logs. But after that request just disappears, and there is no track of request on server side, but on client side it's giving timeout.

- There is no track in Apache Logs
- No system-time issue on client side

I'm not able to debug it, or I'm following a wrong approach. Any idea what might go wrong here.

UPDATE - As it turns out, problem was FD limit related.

Comment: It's tricky to try to narrow it down if it only occurs on certain clients. However keep in mind that some browsers may limit the number of AJAX requests done to the same server to only say 3 at a time. Not sure if this is relevant though. Maybe log the client user agent to see if this only happens on certain browsers.

Comment: On client side it's a JavaFX Application

Comment: At any rate, I'd take a look at the client side application for any bugs since this doesn't look like a laravel-side issue.